# Swift: create algorithm for grouping array items

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, algorithm, grouping

I have an array of arrays.

```
 [
     [3, 5], 
     [5, 1], 
     [9, 8], 
     [5, 3], 
 ]
```

First two arrays have similar value "5". That means that they should be in one group. That means that all their values should be items in that group. So, first group will be 3, 5, 1.

As a result I should have all groups which has similar items:

```
 [[3, 5, 1]]
```

The last array  `[5, 3]` is not in the output because those items are already included. So, basically the output is array of Sets.

What is the best way to make this kind of algorithm?

The first that is coming to my mind is iteration, but that is very bad solution.

---

for example this set:

```
[[1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [5,6], [6,5], [12,11], [8,9],]
```

should give a results

```
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6]]
```

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do here? What should be the output for `[[3,5],[5,1],[1,8]]`?

Comment: @Sweeper algorithm for grouping items

Comment: What is the expected result of the entire array?

Comment: @vadian [[3, 5, 1]]  there is explanation, check the post please

Comment: Why is the last array `[5, 3]` not in the output? Are they "similar" because the last item from one array is the same as the first item from the next?

Comment: @Fogmeister the last array not in the output because those items already included. So, basically output is array of Sets

Comment: @Fogmeister but if you can help me with general algorithm without that Set feature, i will be very happy.

Comment: @Fogmeister, it looks like he wants to combine all intersecting sub-arrays and get `Set` of their elements. Some kind of `clustering` algorithm.

Comment: I get why `[5,3]` is not included in the original example but what about the `[1,8]` in Sweeper's example? The `1` is obviously included in the previous subsets so do you add the `8` too or not?

Comment: @assoron in that case the result will be all items  [[3, 5, 1, 8]]  because all subarrays share one item with each other

Comment: @Sweeper sorry,did not get your question. in that case the result will be all items [[3, 5, 1, 8]] because all subarrays share one item with each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this would be using a dictionary. You could accumulate all groups under their elements. Then each element that has more than one group is the one you are looking for. Take a look into this example:

```
func findClusterValues(inGroups groups: [[Int]]) -> [Int] {
    var map: [Int: [[Int]]] = [Int: [[Int]]]()
    groups.forEach { group in
        group.forEach { element in
            var items: [[Int]] = map[element] ?? [[Int]]()
            items.append(group)
            map[element] = items
        }
    }
    var set: Set<Int> = Set<Int>()
    map.forEach { key, value in
        if value.count > 1 {
            value.forEach { array in
                array.forEach { item in
                    set.insert(item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return Array<Int>(set)
}
```

This could be highly improved with some flat-maps to say the least. Also probably sets could already have been used inside the `map` dictionary instead of arrays of arrays. But this should be enough for demonstration for now.

So the actual numbers are used as keys here. And every key will include all groups that include element with the same value. When all is distributed we check if any of the keys has more than 1 groups and we extract all numbers from all of those groups and insert them into a Set. Set will automatically remove our duplicates for us and we can then return it back as an array (group).

A new algorithm as requested in comments needs a bit more work:

```
typealias Group = [Int]
class Cluster {
    private(set) var uniqueElements: Set<Int> = Set<Int>()
    private(set) var groups: [Group] = [Group]()

    init() {}
    convenience init(group: Group) {
        self.init()
        insertGroup(group)
    }

    func insertGroup(_ group: Group) {
        groups.append(group)
        group.forEach { uniqueElements.insert($0) }
    }
    func merge(cluster: Cluster?) {
        guard let cluster = cluster, cluster !== self else { return }
        cluster.groups.forEach { insertGroup($0) }
    }
    func deplete() {
        groups = [Group]()
        uniqueElements = Set<Int>()
    }
}

func findClusterValues(inGroups groups: [Group]) -> [Group] {
    var map: [Int: Cluster] = [Int: Cluster]()

    groups.forEach { group in
        let newCluster = Cluster(group: group)
        newCluster.uniqueElements.forEach { value in
            newCluster.merge(cluster: map[value])
        }
        newCluster.uniqueElements.forEach { value in
            map[value] = newCluster
        }
    }

    return map.compactMap { key, cluster in
        guard cluster.groups.count > 1 else { return nil }
        let group = Group(cluster.uniqueElements)
        cluster.deplete()
        return group
    }
}
```

Now clusters are introduced which populate a part of dictionary that their elements correspond to. When a new cluster collides with existing one it basically consumes it and increases in size.

At the end the clusters that have only 1 group are removed. Those removed are then depleted (all groups removed) so that duplicates are avoided.

Comment: for example this set [["1","2"], ["2","3"], ["3","4"], ["5","6"], ["6","5"], ["12","11"], ["8","9"],] should give a results [[1,2,3,4],[5,6]]

Comment: are you able to fix that?

Comment: @kuwhkud That makes a completely different algorithm. You should have described these situations in your question instead of letting us guess what you want to achieve. Anyway, yes, I am able to fix that. Please check the update; I have added extra version of this method.